# Scaling tikz-cd labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, scaling, tikz-cd

I'd like to scale a custom symbol drawn in `tikz`, such that it's the same size as surrounding text in a `tikz-cd` diagram.

For example, in the following code I'd like the box to the left of `A_2` to be proportionally the same as the box to the left of `A_1`: currently it's the boxes are the same size, even though `A_2` is smaller than `A_1`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\boxL}{%
  \tikz[baseline=0em,xscale=0.02em,yscale=0.02em]
  \fill (1,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle;\mspace{1mu}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
{\boxL A_1} \rar{\boxL A_2} & A_3
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, `tikz-cd` uses `\scriptstyle` for labels, which is good, but the box in the label isn't getting scaled properly.

For the record, this can be fixed if the equation is replaced with:

```
{\boxL A_1} \rar{\scriptsize\boxL A_2} & A_3
```

This results in the following picture:

[image]

However, I don't want to have to add `\scriptsize` explicitly everywhere.

Comment: @Papiro no. I think it might be useful for newcomers.

Comment: I get errors that `\box` is already defined and `\BoxL` is not … — Anyway, as the arrow label is per default in math-mode you can use `amsmath`’s/`amstext`’s `\text` macro so that TikZ picks up the correct `em` size.

Comment: What is ```\rar```?

Comment: @Ramanujan It draws a right arrow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code

```
\documentclass[convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{amstext,tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\BOX}{%
  \text{%
    \tikz[baseline=0em,xscale=0.02em,yscale=0.02em]
    \fill (1,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- cycle;}\mkern1mu\relax}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
{\BOX A_1} \rar{\BOX A_2} & A_3
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\mathchoice` to scale the symbol appropriately depending on the style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand\Mybox{%
  \tikz[baseline=0em,xscale=0.02em,yscale=0.02em]
  \fill (\unit,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,\unit) -- (\unit,\unit) -- cycle;\mspace{1mu}}
\newcommand\Mbox{%
  \mathchoice{\def\unit{1}\Mybox}{\def\unit{1}\Mybox}{\def\unit{0.67}\Mybox}{\def\unit{0.5}\Mybox}
}

\begin{document}

\[ \Mbox_{\Mbox_{\Mbox}} \]

\begin{tikzcd}
{\Mbox A_1} \rar{\Mbox A_2} & A_3
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]